# Scrapy successful but won't output any information?

Tags: python, terminal, scrapy, output

I've made a lot of headway with this spider- am just growing accustomed to coding and am enjoying every minute of it. However, as I'm learning the majority of my programming is problem solving. Here's my current error:

My spider shows all of the data I want in the terminal window. When I go to output, nothing shows up. Here is my code.

```
import re
import json
from urlparse import urlparse


from scrapy.selector import Selector
try:
    from scrapy.spider import Spider
except:
    from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider as Spider
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from database.items import databaseItem

from scrapy.log import *

class CommonSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'fenders.py'
    allowed_domains = ['usedprice.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.usedprice.com/items/guitars-musical-instruments/fender/?ob=model_asc#results']

    rules = (

        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=( )), callback='parse_item'),
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = []
        data = hxs.select('//tr[@class="oddItemColor baseText"]')
        tmpNextPage = hxs.select('//div[@class="baseText blue"]/span[@id="pnLink"]/a/@href').extract()
        for attr in data:
        #item = RowItem()
        instrInfo = attr.select('//td[@class="itemResult"]/text()').extract()
        print "Instrument Info: ", instrInfo
        yield instrInfo
```

Comment: parse_item() expects you to yield an item or loader, not a string.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not entirely sure what the implementation of that means though.

Comment: You have your RowItem object commented out just above your instantiation of instrInfo. You should be populating the RowItem and yielding that instead.

Answer (score 0):

As JoeLinux said, you're yielding a string, instead of returning the item.  If you're mostly working off the tutorial, you probably have an "items.py" file someplace (maybe some other name), where you item is defined - it would appear that it's called "RowItem()".  Here you've got several fields, or maybe just one.

What you need to do is figure out how you want to store the data in the item.  So, making a gross assumption, you probably want RowItem() to include a field called instrInfo.  So your items.py file might include something like this:

```
class RowItem(scrapy.Item):
    instrInfo = scrapy.Field()
```

Then your spider should include something like:

```
item = RowItem()

data = data = hxs.select('//tr[@class="oddItemColor baseText"]')
for attr in data:
    instrInfo = attr.select('//td[@class="itemResult"]/text()').extract()
    item['instrInfo'].append = instrInfo
return item
```

This will send the item off to your pipeline for processing.

As I said, some gross assumptions about what you're trying to do, and the format of your information, but hopefully this gets you started.

Separately, the print function probably isn't necessary.  When the item is returned, it's displayed in the terminal (or log) as the spider runs.

Good luck!